# How to implement Pinch to Zoom using Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.3

I am trying to implement Pinch/Zoom feature in one of my app using sencha touch 2. I have searched the web for the solution, and what I have found out that most of the solutions are for old version of sencha touch, (https://github.com/Sang-Oh/PinchZoomImage, https://market.sencha.com/extensions/pinch-zoom-image) and I couldn't implement any one of those. And now I am trying to implement this - [Pinch-to-Zoom on Panels with HTML in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044452/pinch-to-zoom-on-panels-with-html-in-sencha-touch-2), but this one doesn't work properly. Is there any way to implement the Pinch to Zoom using Sencha Touch 2.3?

Comment: I have been using succesfully this implementation with Sencha Touch 2.1.1:
https://github.com/SunboX/ST2_ImageViewer
It could be worth giving it a try for your project.

Comment: @Anubis thx, let me try.....

Comment: @Anubis not working....couldn't make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this by including iScroll.js in the project. See http://iscrolljs.com/#zoom for its documentation. It's working nicely for us however it required some time to set up properly.

Comment: I am not doing that project for a long time... I will be testing your plugin soon.. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I assumed you have solved it (or not) since the question was posted. But I thought the solution we have used might be useful for others.

Comment: Glad I could help solving a long standing problem for you.

Comment: there is an issue, if i use this in a carousel, then after zooming in the image and scrolling the zoomed image to the right/left take me to the next/previous image. Any solution?

Comment: That's an application logic issue. Obviously scrolling and swiping conflicts here. Generally it's not the best idea to use both of them at the same time. The solution might be to stop event propagation when the image is already zoomed.